# Extremely large sequence and acknowledge numbers when using Scapy

Tags: ip, tcp, packet-analysis, network, layer4

I am using Scapy to try and read the seq and ack numbers of tcp packets using the following sample code:

```
packet = sniff(iface=argv[1], prn=scan, filter="", count=1)[0]
print "Found SEQ " + str(packet.getlayer(TCP).seq) +" ACK " + str(packet.getlayer(TCP).ack)
```

However,I found the numbers to be extremely large like  3786938882 and 298237083. When I view the packets in wireshark, their values were only like 65 and 150 for example. Am I supposed to put the values into some sort of formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP actually starts with a large, random, 32-bit sequence number. Scapy appears to be showing you what the sequence numbers actually are.  Wireshark is converting the TCP sequence numbers into relative sequence numbers. see [TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers):

> **TCP Relative Sequence Numbers & TCP Window Scaling**
>
> By default Wireshark and TShark will keep track of all TCP sessions
>   and convert all Sequence Numbers (SEQ numbers) and Acknowledge Numbers
>   (ACK Numbers) into relative numbers. This means that instead of
>   displaying the real/absolute SEQ and ACK numbers in the display,
>   Wireshark will display a SEQ and ACK number relative to the first seen
>   segment for that conversation.
>
> This means that all SEQ and ACK numbers always start at 0 for the
>   first packet seen in each conversation.
>
> This makes the numbers much smaller and easier to read and compare
>   than the real numbers which normally are initialized to randomly
>   selected numbers in the range 0 - (2^32)-1 during the SYN phase.
>
> This usability feature relies on features from
>   TCP_Analyze_Sequence_Numbers so in order to use this feature you must
>   also enable TCP_Analyze_Sequence_Numbers.
>
> Using relative sequence numbers is a usability enhancement, making the
>   numbers easier to read and compare. In order to compare a dissection
>   with data from a less advanced analyzer that can not handle relative
>   sequence numbers it might be required to temporarily disable this
>   feature in Wireshark.
>
> For Wireshark versions prior to 1.5: When the Relative Sequence
>   Numbers preference is enabled Wireshark will also enable "Window
>   Scaling".
>
> For Wireshark 1.5 & newer: "Window Scaling" is a separate TCP
>   preference enabled by default.
>
> If "Window Scaling" is enabled, Wireshark will try to monitor the TCP
>   Window Scaling option negotiated during the SYN phase and if such TCP
>   Window Scaling has been detected, Wireshark will also scale the window
>   field and translate it to the effective window size. This may affect
>   what the dissected and reported window is and may make Wireshark to
>   decode packets differently, but more accurately, than other tools.
>
> To disable relative sequence numbers and instead display them as the
>   real absolute numbers, go to the TCP preferences and untick the box
>   for
>
> [image]
>
> relative sequence numbers.